# What does the mysterious constant marked by C on a slide rule indicate?

Tags: notation, math-history, constants

Years ago, before everyone (or anyone) had electronic calculators, I had a pocket slide rule which I used in secondary school until the first TI-30 cane out.

Recently I dug it out. Here's a photo of one end of it.

[image: Slide rule showing mysterious constant on the C and D scales]

As you can see, there's a number $C$ marked at about $1.128$ (times some power of $10$; with a slide rule you supply that yourself) on the C and D scales. Reading across to the A scale, its square is about $1.27$. By the C1 scale (which reads reciprocals of the C scale) its reciprocal is about $0.886$ (times some power of $10$).

The only two special numbers marked are $C$ and $\pi$.

I'm not sure whether it's some frequently used constant that's used (eg) in some branch of engineering, or a number which is useful for some trick for using the slide rule.

Unlike $\pi$, which is marked on most of the scales, this mysterious $C$ only appears on the C and D scales, which are the main ones used for multiplication and division.

If you need me to, I can give more explanation of the various scales on the rule and how calculations are done. That might give some clues as to what $C$ is for.

I'm sure the instructions explained what $C$ was, but I last saw those in the 1970s.

Has anyone any idea what $C$ is and why it would be useful on a slide rule?

Comment: Please tag as appropriate—I'm not sure if the right tags and can't yet create a new "slide-rules" tag.

Comment: Funnest question in forever.

Comment: Did anyone else here buy their kid a slide rule when he/she went off to engineering school.  My daughter ended up with two (we are a family with many engineers).  She dutifully sat through my instructions on slide rule use (twice), but I don't think she paid any attention.

Comment: Shouldn't this go in retrocomputing.SE? ;-)

Comment: @shoover - good one!

Comment: @Flydog57 - who is this "kid" you're speaking of?  I bought my own damn slide rule (a K&E log log decitrig) _with_ its orangy leather case with belt loop!  And then the first 4-banger calculators came out - bought one for \$120! (A large sum for the time when a college textbook cost \$20-\$25 - eat your heart out, current students!)

Comment: This must be some new-fangled addition to slide rules. My dad's K&E 4080-3 (probably pre-1940) has no such markings. (Yes, I still have the orangy leather case, though the flap has broken.)

Comment: @Llaves All I'm really sure of fanglementwise is that the fangle was in place by about Christmas 1975.

Comment: One of my slides has $C$ but it is exactly at $1.2$.  It has a whole bunch of other letters e.g. $F$ at $1.9$ and some two letter markings e.g. $Cl$ at $3.35ish$.

Comment: Amazingly, [Googling for "C 1.128"](https://www.google.com/search?q=C+1.128) has the first result being [page 130 of this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=E4orDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA130) that has a totally unrelated "C" but has the exact ratio "$1 : 1.128$" given as the final answer to some question, and the line just above that says "$\sqrt{2} : \sqrt{8/3.142}$", from which we can work out what $1.128$ is!

Comment: [ries](https://mrob.com/pub/ries/) tells me $1.128$ is exactly $\frac{(\frac{4}{5})^2}{5}+1$. It's probably not how $C$ has been defined, though.

Comment: Thanks for the question ! I took my slide rule (I did buy it in 1958) and, thanks to you, I nticed that this $C$ was present ! I never noticed. Shame on me !

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I found the answer by googling "slide rule markings"! It took me straight to the [Glossary](https://www.sliderulemuseum.com/SR_Terms.htm) of the [International Slide Rule Museum](https://sliderulemuseum.com/SRM_Home.htm), which gives C its own entry:

> C - Gauge mark found on the C and D scales denoting $\sqrt{4/\pi} = 1.128$ for calculating the area of a circle and the volume of a cylinder. Place the C mark on the C scale over the diameter of a circle on the D scale. The area of the circle is found above the index on the A scale. If this is the base of a cylinder, without moving the slide, move the cursor to the height of the cylinder on the B scale. The volume is read on the A scale. This gauge mark was rendered obsolete with the advent of multi-lined cursors.

And there is, of course, so much more at that site.

Comment: Amazing.  Like a moron I googled 1.128 and didn't get anywhere.

Comment: I've just tried calculating $\sqrt{4/\pi}$ on the slide rule and the result does line up nicely with the $C$ mark, so this is definitely it!. Thanks!

Comment: The museum is amazing! I feel much younger now (maybe that such a musem can make me feel younger should make me feel old...)

Comment: @Francesco "It makes me feel like a kid again, and that just reminds me how long it's been."

Comment: I wish I had that mark on my slide rule.  I am always calculating the volume of a cylinder at the beer joint.  But calculation of the volume of a Starbucks cup is best done with Simpson's rule.

Comment: I seems more suited to finding the diameter of a circle of known area which could be useful in some engineering contexts, especially pipe flow.